# Exploring Phonon Dispersion in Two-Dimensional Materials: Analytical Techniques and Mode Identification

Tags: dispersion, phonons

How can one analyze the phonon dispersion of 2D materials like graphene to discern specific curves corresponding to particular phonon modes, such as acoustic or optical, as well as longitudinal and transverse modes?[image: Phonon dispersion of graphene]